# Total mechanical energy of body of fluid at rest

Tags: potential-energy, fluid-statics

I encountered a claim in a textbook that the total mechanical energy of a body of fluid at rest (with a free surface) is equal to the potential energy of the water at the free surface.

For example, for a reservoir with height of $h$, the mechanical energy per unit mass is $gh$. I certainly agree that all mechanical energy is potential energy here, but it isn't clear to me why the potential energy per mass doesn't differ with height. Can anyone explain?

Additional information:
The statement of the question is

Electric power is to be generated by installing a hydraulic turbine–generator at a site 120 m below the free surface of a large water reservoir that can supply water at a rate of 2400 kg/s steadily. Determine the power generation potential.

I chose to apply Bernoulli between the free surface and the exit of the generator, both at $P_a$. In this case:

$$gh = \frac{1}{2} v_{out}^2$$

The power then is $P = \dot{m} v_{out}^2 =2 \dot{m}g h$

Which is apparently a factor of 2 too large. The solution to the problem involves the energetic reasoning above.

Update: Ok, so I'm missing a factor of 2 in the power, so now the answers agree, but I still don't understand the solution's argument. How come potential energy / unit mass doesn't vary with height?

Comment: Let's assume the river keeps the height constant.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $P=0.5\dot{m}v^2$ to be consistent with Kinetic energy $KE=0.5m v^2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just missing a factor of 2 in the equation for power is all.  Kinetic energy $KE=\frac {1}{2}m v^2$, so the corresponding power carried by the flow should just be  $P=\frac {1}{2}\dot{m} v^2$. It would be even easier to do $P=\dot{m}gh$, which allows you to easily adjust power of the water level decreases.

Comment: Yes, I see that that is where the answers differ. But I still don't understand the solution's logic.

Comment: Just imagine a bit of water with mass dm falling from the top of the damage so it gains energy dm×g×h and gives it to your generator. Now drop dm per dt and you get dEnergy/dt = dm/dt×g×h. It's not one bit that falls the whole way, but that doesn't actually matter in the end.

Comment: Ah ok, this makes sense. The water at the top has only potential energy. As the water flows to the pump, some of this potential energy will become kinetic energy. But nothing removes energy from any given packet of water, so the total energy of all packets of water (KE/mass) is the same as at the top. We just don't know the ratio until the packet is at the pump and it's all kinetic. Somehow this feels conceptually more difficult than for a particle, but you're right, it's the same.